RedFish API on Dell iDRAC - certificate invalid
So we try to use RedFish API to make CSR and then use our CA to create certificate. We have this powershell cmdlet from
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-ExportImportSslCertificateREDFISH/9.0.0
Invoke-GenerateCsrREDFISH -generate_csr -idrac_ip <idracip> -idrac_username root -idrac_password <password> -Country DE -State Baden-Wuertemberg -City Stuttgart -Org Customer -OrgUnit IT -CommonName idrac-8t1t954.m2t.forest

this makes a CSR which we sign using our CA, but the problem is that iDRAC does not like the resulting certificate and it does not matter if we try to upload it using Dell racadm utility or RedFish.
racadm says:
Security Alert: Certificate is invalid - Certificate is not signed by Trusted Third Party
Continuing execution. Use -S option for racadm to stop execution on certificate-related errors.
ERROR: An invalid certificate is uploaded.

Invoke-ReplaceCertificateREDFISH - this also does not work and says Certificate upload failed: Cannot validate the certificate if we try the binary .cer format
or it says
Unable to complete the operation because the value  entered for the
property \u0011 is not in the list of acceptable values
if we try .pem format.
it WORKS if we generate CSR with the same parameters via racadm however. But our company wants us to use RedFish API...
